# What is the advantage of the augmented Lagrange method compared to the quadratic penalty method and the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraint-programming

**p.s.** I already know few things, but it is interesting to listen to different perspectives.

what I know: the augmented Lagrange method combines the penalty method and the method of Lagrange multipliers. The penalty method convergence hinges heavily on the penalty parameter which must tend to $\infty$ to approach the optimal solution. By adding another quadratic constraint, the ALM method relaxes this and hence a finite value of the penalty parameter suffices.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @copper.hat no, just for me to see different perspectives, I already have my own opinion

Comment: @copper.hat what made you think it is a homework :(